# MongoDB and 2dsphere index containing multiple locations

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

In MongoDB collection I want to create `2dsphere` index on a field that consists of *many* locations.

I think it must be posible, since the `$geoNear` stage operator has the options like `includeLocs` or `uniqueDocs` which state that we can specify some conditions if the location field has more than one location.

Then I'm trying to create an index on a field `loc` which looks like:

```
//db.users
{
     //other fields
loc: [
          {type:"Point", coordinates: [-20, 20]},
          {type:"Point", coordinates: [-30, 30]}
     ]
}
```

with the code:

```
db.users.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})
```

But I'm getting the error that `loc` is invalid format.

How can I create an index on a field that have many locations?

Answer (score 2):

In case it could be helpful to somebody: in most cases, whatever the type is, the second field for [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) data object is `coordinates`. So, the following could work not only in my case, but also when there is a mix of different types, like `LineString`, etc. All you need to do is to create index on that particular field of embdeeded document:

```
db.users.createIndex({"loc.coordinates":"2dsphere"})
```